# Listview Clear and memory freeing

Tags: c#, memory-management

I have a program that uses a ListView to print a large amount of data to the user interface. It can fill up to hold more than 500MB of data sometimes, but this isn't my problem. My problem is that if I try to clear the items in the listview via  `listview.Items.Clear();` the memory consumption of my application only goes down a fraction, and sits there. Memory examples from a brand new windows forms application with just a listview in it:

- 7,812K - Program run with no listview items added.
- 26,816K - Populated with 50000 ListView items assigned to the value "test"
- 22,860K - Memory after clearing the previous 50000 ListView items.

Memory values are from Task Manager.

My problem is that listview.Items.Clear() isn't freeing all of the memory taken by the listview items, as far as I can tell.

Relevant information: In my test program, all it contains is a ListView with the 'details' view property, and one column.

Relevant code:

```
public void Test()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem("test"));
    }
}
private void listView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the listview doesn't dispose the items, that is the reason why the memory stays the same.

However, if the items are not referenced anywhere in your project, when garbage collector kicks in they will be disposed properly and the memory will go down again.

Comment: Calling GC.Collect() is usually not recommended since it might cause performance issues in some cases. But if you are really concerned about the memory usage and don't have the luxury of waiting the GC to do it's work then give it a try and see if it affects your application. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx (under the note)

Comment: GC.Collect() Seems to solve my problem, but I keep hearing how bad it is, and I don't want to have negative effects on my program. Is there any other way I can destroy/Dispose the object without calling GC.Collect?

Comment: You can populate the listview with objects that inherit IDisposable, that way you will be able to dispose each one of them.

Comment: I'm not sure how to write a way to write a dispose method, but then again I don't know much about IDisposable and how to use it.

I wonder what the reason is that the memory consumed by my listview never gets cleaned up by GC unless you use GC.Collect();

Comment: GC doesn't run all the time. Just at 'random' intervals cleaning whatever it needs to be cleaned. So when GC does it's routine clean up it will clean those as well.